# Django display and format group names in template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

Having issues getting this information formatted correctly in my template. I've searched google and stack overflow extensively, but I haven't been able to solve this issue.

I'm using django-role-permissions and I've created a bunch of roles, whcih get assigned to the group of each user. I want to display all the groups that they are in on my template with a comma in between. I also want to trade out the '_' between the names with a space. The closest I have come is to get the group names dispayed like the following:

```
Driver Freight_manager System_admin Employee_manager
```

I've tried a few custom templatetags but everything splits it into an individual character with a ',' between. Ultimately, I want it to look like the following, but I can't figure it out:

```
Driver, Freight Manager, System Admin, Employee Manager
```

Here is my template code:

```
{% for g in profile_detail.user.groups.all %}
     {{ g.name|capfirst }}
{% endfor %}
```

I'm assuming that I can do this in a template and don't have to modify the view. Can someone help me with a templatetag or something to get this working? It's driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make templatetag:

```
@register.filter(name='split')
def split(value, arg):
    return " ".join(value.split(arg)).title()
```

**HTML**

```
 {% load <file name of template tag> %}
    {% for g in profile_detail.user.groups.all %}
             {{ g.name|split:'_' }},
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Closer, but not quite there. Output is `['Driver'], ['Freight', 'Manager'], ['System', 'Admin'], ['Employee', 'Manager'],`

Comment: It worked...leave a trailing comma at the end, but I can fix that later. Thanks man. Really appreciate it!